# Как отобразить содержимое в шаблоне в зависимости от нажатой кнопки?

Tags: python-3.x, django

**Имеется:** Python 3.7 Django 2.2. Страница профиля пользователя, на странице три кнопки "Мои посты", "Посты на модерации", "Посты на сайте". У каждой кнопки есть атрибут "name"

**Задача:** При нажатии на одну из кнопок отправить пользователя на шаблон с отфильтрованными постами согласно нажатой кнопки.

**Условия:** Вне зависимости от того какую из трех кнопок нажал пользователь, нужно отправить его на шаблон filter.html где разместить отфильтрованные данные в зависимости от нажатой кнопки...

Я не могу понять как передать во вьюху что была нажата конкретная кнопка, что бы дальше получить отфильтрованные данные...

**URLS.PY**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', login_view, name='login'),
    path('logout/', logout_view, name='logout'),
    path('filter/', objects_filter, name='objects_filter'),
    path('<str:email>/', user_detail, name='user_detail'),
    path('', user_list, name='user_list'),
]
```

**VIEWS.PY**

```
def objects_filter(request):
    template = 'objects/objects_filter.html'

    if request.method == 'POST':
        objects = RealObject.objects.filter(author=request.user)

        if request.POST.get('get_all'):
            context = {
                'objects': objects
            }
            return render(request, template, context)
    if request.POST.get('get_active_false'):
        objects = objects.get(active=False)
        context = {
            'objects': objects
        }
        return render(request, template, context)

    if request.POST.get('get_active_true'):
        objects = objects.get(active=True)
        context = {
            'objects': objects
        }
        return render(request, template, context)

return render(request, template)
```

---

Я конечно понимаю что написано все криво, и что оно вообще не работает, так что пожалуйста не ругайтесь я еще только учусь...

**TEMPLATE.HTML**

```
{% block content %}
    <h1>Добро пожаловать {{ user.first_name }}</h1>

    {% csrf_token %}
    <a class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" href="{% url 'objects_filter' %}" name="get_all" role="button">Все мои объекты <span class="badge badge-light">!!!</span></a>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" href="{% url 'objects_filter' %}" name="get_active_false">Мои объекты на модерации <span class="badge badge-light">!!!</span></button>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" href="{% url 'objects_filter' %}" name="get_active_true">Мои объекты на сайте <span class="badge badge-light">!!!</span></button>

    <a href="{% url 'new_object' %}">Добавить объект</a>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну во первых вот это надо сместить на 1 таб вправо

```
    if request.POST.get('get_active_false'):
        objects = objects.get(active=False)
        context = {
            'objects': objects
        }
        return render(request, template, context)

    if request.POST.get('get_active_true'):
        objects = objects.get(active=True)
        context = {
            'objects': objects
        }
        return render(request, template, context)

return render(request, template)
```

Вместо последней строчки лучше выдавать тоже что и при 'get_all'

Так как пы пользуетесь POST, то придется кнопки обернуть в форму, либо по AJAX отправлять POST запрос с соответсвующими параметрами

AJAX лучше, так как при обновлении страницы, загруженной через POST появляется окошко "Отправить запрос снова?".

Если не хотите использовать AJAX - можете для решения этой проблемы использовать GET запросы, сделав кнопки ссылками вроде `href='?get_all=1'`

Так же я вижу, что вы проверяете фильтр через `.get()`. Если значение, например `get_all`, не указано в HTML, то request.POST.get('get_all') вернет None, что эквивалентно False (так же как 0, пустая строка, пустые массивы и тп). Пришлите HTML код кнопок для более точного решения вопроса

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'post',
  url: ...,
  data: {
    // pushed_btn_name - name-аттрибут нажатой кнопки
    pushed_btn_name: true, // Или другое значение, на ваш вкус
  },
  success: function (data) {
    // Если html - заменяем блок контента на data - ваш вариант
    // Если JSON - то заполняем этими данными через JS, или можно исползовать JsRender, он для этого удобен
  }
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

Рещение для GET

```
{% block content %}
    <h1>Добро пожаловать {{ user.first_name }}</h1>

    {% csrf_token %}
    <a class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" href="{% url 'objects_filter' %}" name="get_all" role="button">Все мои объекты <span class="badge badge-light">!!!</span></a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" href="{% url 'objects_filter' %}" name="get_all" role="button">Все мои объекты <span class="badge badge-light">!!!</span></a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'objects_filter' %}?get_all">
        Все мои объекты <span class="badge badge-light">!!!</span>
    </a>
    {# Остальные кнопки также, меняется только значение после `?` #}

    <a href="{% url 'new_object' %}">Добавить объект</a>

{% endblock %}
```

В питоне условия сравнения заменить с `request.POST.get('get_active_true')` на `'get_active_true' in request.GET`

Для POST

```
<form>
   {% csrftoken %}
   <input type="submit" value="Показать все" name="get_all" class="btn btn-primary">
  {# и тд с остальными кнопками. кнопку на дополнение можно оставить #}
</form>
```

У button элемента нет атрибута href, почитайте доку по html элементам

Comment: Добавил html в вопрос.

Comment: Обновил ответ на вопрос

Comment: Не могу понять как теперь должен выглядеть views.py.... Я исправил все как вы указали, но что-то явно делаю не правильно...

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95863/ присодинитесь, поговорим там, чтоб комменты не засорять